# How would I detect what is an Imgur picture link, and what isn't?

Tags: regex, url, web, language-agnostic, imgur

I'm trying to programmatically figure out whether or not an link is a link to an Imgur image or not. An example of an Imgur image link would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KygT3.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYvxm.jpg (the first is an indirect link and the latter is direct, but the ID stays the same)

I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/KygT3.jpg to evaluate to `true` when asked if an Imgur link, but http://imgur.com/gallery to be `false`. I'm confused how to distinguish between those two when they're both `imgur.com/*letters*`.

I ask because I know [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com) has this functionality. If I post http://imgur.com/gallery it doesn't offer an image button to preview it, but it would for https://i.stack.imgur.com/KygT3.jpg

So how would I be able to identify this? Finding every word that doesn't qualify, like `gallery`, `jobs`, or `about` in `imgur.com/*whatever*` would seem really hacky, and would break upon any new page being added. And there's not *always* numbers in the second part so I can't rely on that to identify it.

Comment: Surely you have a preferred framework for doing this.  Consider that you should first parse the URL with a proper URL parser, and then apply tests to both the hostname and the relative path components (possibly also checking protocol, port, etc)  There's a highly developed science of URL obfuscation which is designed to defeat string pattern-based testing.

Comment: A framework for what? Specifically targeting Imgur links? Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: A framework you use for most of your applications development.  Are you making this as a web service?  Then something like ASP.NET or PHP or Rails.  Even if you're open to other implementations, say what you're most familiar with.

Comment: I'm doing this through iOS (Swift/Objective-C), so there's definitely URL parsing capabilities, I just want to know what I should be working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Run this snippet for a JavaScript example**

```js
$(function(){
  
    var url_re = /https?[^<"]+/g  /* pattern for url-like substrings */
    
    var txt = $(".post-text").html(); /* taking this question text as input */
  
 while(m = url_re.exec(txt)){ /* match all url-like substrings in input */
      
        /* verify if it's a imgur URL */
      
  var imgur_re = /^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)?imgur.com\/(\w*\d\w*)+(\.[a-zA-Z]{3})?$/
        
        
        /* Show result */
        
        $("#results").append("<li>" + m + ": " + imgur_re.test(m) + "</li>");
 }
  
});
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>

<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
<p>I'm trying to programmatically figure out whether or not an link is a link to an Imgur image or not. An example of an Imgur image link would be: <a href="http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4" rel="nofollow">http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4</a> or <a href="http://i.imgur.com/0AKSCQ4.jpg" rel="nofollow">http://i.imgur.com/0AKSCQ4.jpg</a> (the first is an indirect link and the latter is direct, but the ID stays the same)</p>

<p>I want <a href="http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4" rel="nofollow">http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4</a> to evaluate to <code>true</code> when asked if an Imgur link, but <a href="http://imgur.com/gallery" rel="nofollow">http://imgur.com/gallery</a> to be <code>false</code>. I'm confused how to distinguish between those two when they're both <code>imgur.com/*letters*</code>.</p>

<p>I ask because I know <a href="http://redditenhancementsuite.com" rel="nofollow">Reddit Enhancement Suite</a> has this functionality. If I post <a href="http://imgur.com/gallery" rel="nofollow">http://imgur.com/gallery</a> it doesn't offer an image button to preview it, but it would for <a href="http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4" rel="nofollow">http://imgur.com/0AKSCQ4</a></p>

<p>So how would I be able to identify this? Finding every word that doesn't qualify, like <code>gallery</code>, <code>jobs</code>, or <code>about</code> in <code>imgur.com/*whatever*</code> would seem really hacky, and would break upon any new page being added. And there's not <em>always</em> numbers in the second part so I can't rely on that to identify it.</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just an alternative regex for parsing out an ID. This will match with/without "http(s)://", and extract the ID from i.imgur.com URLs (accounting for thumbnail suffixes and webms), gallery images (which can be retrieved as a plain image from the imgur API, which I'm using), and of course regular image. Note "www." is not matched, since imgur should automatically redirect without the "www.", so people shouldn't supply such URLs. `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:i\.)?imgur\.com\/(?:gallery\/)?(.+(?=[sbtmlh]\..{3,4})|.+(?=\..{3,4})|.+?(?=\s))`

Comment: Edit to fix anchoring to the end (my use case requires links to be detected in middle of text as well): `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:i\.)?imgur\.com\/(?:gallery\/)?(.+(?=[sbtmlh]\..{3,4})|.+(?=\..{3,4})|.+?(?:(?=\s)|$))`

Answer (score 1):

This Regex:

```
/(?>https?:)?\/\/(\w+\.)?imgur\.com\/(\S*)(\.[a-zA-Z]{3})/m
```

will match:

```
https://i.imgur.com/55bm5QS.png
//i.stack.imgur.com/raU7t.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/raU7t.png
```

The regex provided by kums does not match this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/raU7t.png